# Get index of selected node in a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

How can I get the index of a selected node in its parent. For example `D` should be index 3 in `root`. I tried with `jTree.getSelectionPath()` but it doesn't show the index

```
root
     A
     B
     C
        a
     D
        a
        b
        c
     E
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JTree has the methods

```
public int[] getSelectionRows()
public int getMinSelectionRow()
public int getMaxSelectionRow()
```

Comment: Yes I tried with that but for D returns 4 instead of 3 because in C theres one node "a"

Comment: If you need index of child element you can get parent node and use int getIndex(TreeNode node) passing the child